# what is u,v image coordinates?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, 3d, coordinate-transformation

I saw `u,v image coordinates` at bottom of [here](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/handtracker/data/GANeratedDataset/README.txt). I downloaded the data and one sample is `[214.65  222.52  145.72  165.42   96.492 114.22   64.985  71.877  43.323
  33.477 128.98  173.29  120.12  160.49  121.11  134.89  128.     98.462
 175.26  177.23  177.23  151.63  178.22  130.95  177.23   98.462 212.68
 175.26  214.65  118.15  215.63   80.738 208.74   68.923 249.11  173.29
 242.22  122.09  237.29   86.646 234.34   48.246]`.

I did search but did not find explanation of `u,v image coordinates` and how to convert to x-y coordinates. It is not [UV mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping), because the data is not between [0, 1]. I may be wrong.

any comments welcomed. Thanks

Comment: They might be absolute pixel coordinates instead of normalized ones (which UVs should be), i.e. either that project adopts a different definition of "UV" or whoever wrote the documentation was wrong.

Comment: The most likely case that its just non-normalized UV mapping

Answer (score 0):

To be more confident, we can plot these points using Matlab/Octave or OpenCV on the corresponding color image and see if their positions match to the labeled joints. For joint structure we can look at the same [README file](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/handtracker/data/GANeratedDataset/README.txt) `W, T0, T1, T2, T3, I0, I1, I2, I3, M0, M1, M2, M3, R0, R1, R2, R3, L0, L1, L2, L3.` Every joint has 2 coordinates so the sequence of 42 numbers correspond to u, v (X, Y) coordinates of corresponding joints in the sequence.

I tried to directly plot an image and 2D points in Matlab/Octave using this code:

```
clc; clear;

im = imread('0001_color_composed.png');
data = csvread('0001_joint2D.txt');
x = zeros(length(data)/2,1);
y = x;

for i = 1: length(data)/2
    x(i) = data(2*i-1);
    y(i) = data(2*i);
end

imshow(im);
hold on;
plot(x, y, 'go');
```

and these [image](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/handtracker/data/GANeratedDataset/data/noObject/0001/0001_color_composed.png) and [annotation](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/handtracker/data/GANeratedDataset/data/noObject/0001/0001_joint2D.txt). As you can see in the resulting image below all u, v coordinates correspond to pixel coordinates in X and Y counted from the top left corner of image in pixels, i.e. u = X, v = Y (as if image shown using `imshow()`, the origin of the coordinate frame for consecutive plots is set to the image coordinate frame origin which is the top left corner).

[image]